# error C2143: syntax error

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Хотел вынести все используемые объявленные структуры в отдельный файл.
Вынес.

```
//file: Structs.h
#pragma once
#include "stdafx.h"// тут все библиотеки: и vector, и все остальные.

struct SSource
{
    vector<AVFilterContext *> src;
};
struct Initing
{
    vector<AVFormatContext *> out_ifcx;
    vector<AVCodecContext *> out_iccx;

    vector<AVFormatContext *> ifcx;
    vector<AVCodecContext *> iccx;

    vector<SSource> afcx;

    vector<AVFilterGraph *> graphVec;
    vector<AVFilterContext *> sinkVec;
};
```

VS2013 пишет для каждой структуры (6 строчка - `vector<AVFilterContext *> src;`):

> Structs.h(6): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<' 
>   Structs.h(6): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note:
>   C++ does not support default-int
>  
>   Structs.h(6): error C2238: unexpected
>   token(s) preceding ';'

Что ему не нравится? В заголовочных файлах, где я использую эти структуры, пишу после #include ов (`#include "Structs.h"` присутствует):

```
struct Initing;
struct SSource;
struct CAVPacket2;
```

**UPDATE:** проблема решилась: не хватало `std::` для `vector<type>`

Comment: `vector` находится в `namespace std`, а следовательно `std::vector`, или вы прямо в хедер `stdafx.h` впехнули `using namesapce std` (если да, то не делайте так в хедерах)?

Comment: @StateItPrimitive Да! спасибо. Нет, using namespace в хедере нет. Забыл его дописать в Structs.h и VS не подчеркнула, что ей не понятно, где брать вектор

Comment: `Забыл его дописать в Structs.h`. Правило "не помещать `using namespace` внутрь файла", касается всех `*.h` файлов.

Comment: @alexolut имел ввиду дописать std::. Я и не помещаю)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо StateItPrimitive (см. комментарии к вопросу).

Решение: 
**`std`**`::vector<type> a;`
 Не хватало определения к какому namespace относится. В данном случает std.